# postgresql left join but dont fetch if matching condition found

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a bit of a complicated scenario.  I have two tables, `employee` and `agency`.  An employee may or may not have an agency, but if an employee has an agency I want the select clause to check another condition on the agency, but if the employee does not have an agency its fine I want to fetch the employee.  I'm not sure how to write the select statement for this.  This is what I have come up with so far

```
select * from employee e left join
agency a on a.id = e.agencyID and a.valid = true;
```

However the problem with this is that it fetches both employees without agencies which is fine, but it also fetches employees with agencies where `a.valid = false`. The only option I can think of is to do an union but I'm looking for something more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

A `UNION` could actually be the solution that performs best, but you can write the query without `UNION` like this:

```
select *
from employee e
   left join agency a
      on a.id = e.agencyID
where coalesce(a.valid, true);
```

That will accept agencies where `valid IS NULL`, that is, result rows where the `agency` part was substituted with NULLs by the outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You want except the condition that both table match(agency.id = employee.agencyID) and also agency.id is false. The following query will express the condition.

```
SELECT
    e.*,
    a.*
FROM
    employee e
    LEFT JOIN agency a ON a.id = e.agencyID
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            agency
        WHERE
            a.id = e.agencyID
            AND a.valid IS FALSE)
ORDER BY
    e.id;
```